# Laravel filesize of a pictures that is uploaded

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to output the filesize of an image that is stored in this location:

> storage/app/public/filename.jpg

When I do this:

```
filesize(public_path($picture->filename));
```

I get the following error:

> filesize(): stat failed for
>   agrant/Code/public/public/H0afvcjKJN3ecEUAf8qx6VlRFqDuVDOkOGwnfY3y.jpeg

Comment: Try when you upload image `$request->file('file')->getClientSize();` and from public path `File::size(public_path($picture->filename));`

Comment: @HirenGohel What class should I use for the File::size function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You stored your file in the storage folder. You should use the function

```
storage_path('app/public/'.$picture->filename);
```

Access to the public folder works only if you used the `php artisan storage:link` command, to create a symbolic link.

Also

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

$size = Storage::size('public/'.$picture->filename');
```

should work out.

Answer (score 0):

This code get your size of file in that you already stored
    use File;

```
// add this with in your function
$size = File::size($PATH_OF_FILE)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.